# Azure app service - docker container - take latest build after CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

Through VSTS we have created CI/CD pipeline for a project, in which the end product is a docker image, which will be placed in a azure container registry.

In the azure app service, we have a linux container based service plan, which hosts the above placed latest image.

However, in the docker container, although we have enabled continuous deployment, the *latest* version is not taken, it is hosting the same older version of image.

How to deploy the latest docker image in app service container ?

Comment: What're tasks of your build and release definitions? Do you check Include Latest tag option? Post the detail build and release log here (remove personal information).

Answer (score 1):

Azure Container Registry webhooks can be used to automatically update your application running on Azure App Services that run your container applications.

Setup your image to deploy to your Azure Web App on Linux as per the instruction at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-linux-using-custom-docker-image#how-to-use-a-docker-image-from-a-private-image-registry

In the App Settings section of your Web Application, add an app setting called DOCKER_ENABLE_CI with the value true.

Create a web hook in your registry and provide the docker callback uri which is of the form https://:@.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook
    https://:@.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook

E.g. https://github.com/sajayantony/appservicedemo